# Excel doesn't release a shape's creation name

Tags: excel, vba

I’m posting this in the hope that it might help someone else, as none of my searches revealed any information regarding this.

I ran into this while building a procedure that would copy an imbedded form shape, and paste it on the same sheet, then run a renaming scheme that would facilitate referencing either of these shapes

This should be simple enough, but I was running into an intermittent problem.  Eventually I came to realize that Excel appears to “remember” the shape’s original name at the time of its creation, and keeps it flagged as being in use, releasing it only when the shape is deleted.  So if you rename the shape, you can never return it to the original name.  E.g., if you rename “Button 1” to “Btn1”, you can never change it back to “Button 1”.  Interestingly, you can now reference the shape by either name, “Button 1” or “Btn1”.

In the macro below, assuming “Button 1” is the creation name, s.Name will end up as “Btn1”, even though it looks like it would return to “Button 1”.

```
Sub RenameShape()
Dim s As Shape
Dim nm As String
Set s = ActiveSheet.Shapes("Button 1")
nm = s.Name
s.Name = "Btn1"
s.Name = nm
End Sub
```

I have since come across a couple of links that talk about the shape’s  “internal” and “external” names – I’m assuming the “internal” name is the inaccessible one that Excel won’t forget, while the “external” name is the exposed name that one normally sees.

I’d be interested to hear from anyone who can shed more insight into this.

Comment: I think [How to get Shape's internal name](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3746558/4717755) may shed some insight into this situation.

Comment: That's an interesting article, which leads me to the conclusion that if one does not already know what the internal name is, there's no way to get it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the main purpose of this post was to pass along information, I'm going to make this an answer so it can be closed.